# android drawPoint() not drawing anything

Tags: java, android, graphics2d, ondraw

I am an amateur programmer, and have been playing around with android development.  I am currently trying my hand at generating a fractal heightmap.  In order to test if teh map is generating properly I need to be able to draw the map to the screen.  This is where I've been running into trouble.

Here's the code for my MainActivity, DrawMap class (where my onDraw() is), and my CanvasThread() class.

Main Activity:

```
package com.psstudios.HMG;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button Startgen = null;
Boolean run=true;

private void log(String text) {
    Log.d("heightmap",text);
    AppendLog app = new AppendLog(text);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Startgen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startgen);

    log("loop");
    Startgen.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            log("Starting world generation");
            WorldGen world=new WorldGen(200,200);
            log("World generation complete, drawing heightmap");
            setContentView(new DrawMap(MainActivity.this, world));
            log("Went too far");
        }
    });
    run=false;

}   

}
```

DrawMap:

```
package com.psstudios.HMG;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.*;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

import android.util.Log;
import android.util.*;


public class DrawMap extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
int drawtype=1;             //variable for which type of map to draw 
Bitmap drawbitmap=null;
CanvasThread canvasThread=null;
Boolean run= true;

int Worldx=200;
int Worldy=200;

WorldGen _world=null;

public void log(String text){
    Log.d("Heightmap", text);
    AppendLog app = new AppendLog(text);    
}

public void init(){
    log("init();");
    canvasThread=new CanvasThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
    log("Post-CanvasThread");
}

public DrawMap(Context context){
    super(context);
    log("DrawMap(Context context)");
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    init();
}

public DrawMap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    log("DrawMap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)");
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    init();

}

public DrawMap(Context context,WorldGen world){
    super(context); 
    log("DrawMap(Context context, WorldGen world)");
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    _world=world;
    init();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,int width, int height){
    log("surfaceChanged()");
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    log("Surface Created");
    canvasThread.setRunning(true);
    canvasThread.run();
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    log("Surface Destroyed");
    Boolean retry = true;
    canvasThread.setRunning(false);
    while(retry){
        try {
            canvasThread.join();
            retry=false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //we will try again and again
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    log("onDraw()");
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Paint paint2 = new Paint();
    //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint2.setColor(Color.BLUE);


    for(int x=0; x<Worldx-1; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<Worldy-1; y++){
            //log(x + " : " + y);
            canvas.drawPoint(x+20, y+20, paint);
            canvas.drawPoint(x+220, y+220, paint2);
        }
    }
}
}
```

CanvasThread:

```
package com.psstudios.HMG;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.*;
import android.util.Log;

public class CanvasThread extends Thread
{
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private DrawMap _drawMap;
    private Boolean _run = false;

    private void log(String text){
        Log.d("HeightmapGen",text);
        AppendLog app = new AppendLog(text);
    }

    public CanvasThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, DrawMap drawMap){
        _surfaceHolder=surfaceHolder;
        _drawMap=drawMap;
        log("CanvasThread()");
    }

    public void setRunning(Boolean run){
        log("setRunning()");
        _run=run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("run()");
        Canvas c;
        while(_run){
            c=null;
            try{
                c=_surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                    _drawMap.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if(c != null){
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program makes it to the onDraw(); function, and runs through the for loop, but nothing is showing up on the screen.  I imagine I'm missing something pretty stupid, but I cannot seem to figure out what's wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me.

Comment: Maybe did you found fix? I have same issue.